# How do we use distinct in left join of mysql

Tags: group-by, inner-join, distinct

I am using PHP and MySQL for my application.

I have a table "Enquiries" with PK enquiry_id and a table "Enquiry_comments" with FK enquiry_id. There will be multiple comments for each enquiry. In my join how do I show the last comment only against each enquiry?

> SELECT * FROM `enquiries` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `enquiry_comments` AS `ec`
>   ON `ec`.`enquiry_id` = `e`.`enquiry_id` WHERE `e`.`status` = 'Active'
>   ORDER BY `e`.`enquiry_id` DESC LIMIT 10

The above query gives me duplicate records so I want to use `group by or distinct` on `enquiry_id` and `order by` `enquiry_comment_id DESC` for enquiry_comments and show only the recent comment with the listing.

**The Table Structure:**

Table Enquiries

```
enquiry_id  enquiry_about enquiry_date
1           PHP           2017-09-20
2           MySQL         2017-08-21
```

Table Enquiry_comments

```
enquiry_comment_id enquiry_id enquiry_comment enquiry_comment_date
1                     1       PHP is Easy     2017-08-03
2                     1       PHP is Ver 7    2017-09-17
3                     2       MySQK is RDBS   2017-09-13
```

From the above example data I want to get the latest one comment with each enquiry so `PHP` should get one comment with `enquiry_comment_id 2` which is latest and `MySQL` get the `enquiry_comment_id 3`

***The Listing Data I want***

```
1   PHP    PHP is Ver 7    2017-09-17
2   MySQL  MySQK is RDBS   2017-09-13
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it? It make the question much clearer, and help us help you. Also, what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I don't even see any evidence that a comment has a date associated with it.  Please edit your question and show us table definitions and some sample data.

Comment: @Mureinik Thanks I have edited the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, The question is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    t1.enquiry_id,
    t1.enquiry_about,
    (SELECT t2.enquiry_comment FROM Enquiry_comments t2
     WHERE t2.enquiry_id = t1.enquiry_id
     ORDER BY t2.enquiry_comment_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS enquiry_comment,
    (SELECT MAX(t2.enquiry_comment_date) FROM Enquiry_comments t2
     WHERE t2.enquiry_id = t1.enquiry_id) AS enquiry_comment_date
FROM Enquiries t1
ORDER BY t1.enquiry_id;
```

For each record in the `Enquiries` table, this query does a subquery on `Enquiry_comments` and selects the latest comment for each parent enquiry.  To find the latest record it uses an `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT` trick.  To also find the corresponding latest comment date, we can just use a simple subquery with the `MAX()` function.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester